# how to change stb_image order RGBA to ARGB?

Tags: cairo, stb-image

i am using stb_image to read image data, i have a trouble about image data channel ordering.

As is see in this library, they have define enum like below, but never use.

```
enum {
    STBI_ORDER_RGB,
    STBI_ORDER_BGR
};
```

By default, all output data with order RGB. But my target is using this data to render on cairo surface, need like below:

```
p = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | (blue << 0);
```

Can i find new stb_image library or i need to refer to other method?
Thanks.